# How to replace Fixed String to NULL from Text File Through Batch File

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have text File in that I want to replace NULL string with ""(NULL). The content of the text file as test.txt is :

```
abc,1234,qwe,NULL
234,NULL,wer,jkl
jkl,678,987,NULL
```

I am expecting my output in test.txt as follows:

```
abc,1234,qwe,
234,,wer,jkl
jkl,678,987,
```

I'm new to this, Kindly help me out thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code out:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

The above mentioned code is taken from [here](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace). If you want to save the output save this batch file and run the following command.

```
C:\> <name of the above batch file> "NULL" "" originalFile.txt > test.txt
```

Hope it helps.

---

**Update**

Here is another alternative to perform a global search and replace function.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set filename=input.txt
set originalText=NULL
set "replacedText="

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %filename%') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=%%line:%originalText%=%replacedText%%%"
        echo !line!>> test.txt
    ) else (
        echo.
    )
)
```

`call set "line=%%line:%originalText%=%replacedText%%%"` will be responsible in performing search and replace of the `NULL` word in the text file. The program will then store the result into `test.txt`.

P.S. Note that `call set` is needed as it will expand the variable that is passed on the same line.

Comment: Do You have any other approach I want simpler one bcoz I'm new to this and I have already written batch file for processing that file I want to incorporate this in same batch file, kindly suggest some other approach

Comment: This approach is somehow working but not exactly and problem is that at the every end of the line it's showing 1 blank space, which is not desireable.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix/Linux:

```
cat <original file> | sed 's/NULL//' > <new file>
```

Comment: It's the same thing - insert this command into your batch script. Are you in MS Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm in MS Windows

Comment: for me it's saying cat it not an internal or external command

Comment: Aleksey, cat is not a native windows command, and neither is sed.

Comment: @foxidrive - yes, you are right, my "cat" came from the MinGW utilities

Comment: FWIW `TYPE` is the Windows equivalent of `CAT` for text files, but `SED` isn't native.  There are ports of sed which are very useful, but `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat is a good replacement for sed for many uses, and is a native jscript solution that doesn't need external tools.  The syntax is not exactly the same and not as comprehensive but it handles much of the windows version of regexp.